# Create condition based loop, copy part of row and use header title

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have been trying to create a VBA which converts a raw data source into a useful dashboard for reporting.

The challenges I encountered:
- Loop across columns, dismiss empty cells and continue loop afterwards
- Copy multiple sections of input table into destination table
- Use column heading of input table as column item in destination table

To show you the desired outcome, I have attached a snippet with an input and destination table.

Any ideas how to solve for this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help

[Snippet of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp43c.png)

Comment: Please post what you have accomplished this far. You will get better help that way

Answer (score 0):

Heyho,

are you just looking for help with the algorithm?

Well you could do sth like the following:

```
    Dim range, cell as Range
    Dim rowDesiredOutputTable
    Set range = ActiveSheet.Range("D5:F9")
    Set rowDesiredOutputTable = 15

    for each cell in range
       if Not(cell.value = vbNullString) Then
       WIth ActiveSHeet
' for adding the company and country
          .Range("B" & rowDesiredOutputTable).Value =.Cells(cell.row, 2).Value
          .Range("C" & rowDesiredOutputTable).Value = .Cells(cell.row, 3).Value
       End with
       If cell.Column = 4 Then
          ActiveSheet.Range("D" & rowDesiredOutputTable).Value = "5 yr"
       Else if cell.column = 5 Then
 'here for 10 yr
       else 
 'here for 15 yr
       end if
       ActiveSheet.Range("E" & rowDesiredOutputTable).Value = cell.Value
       End if
    next cell
```

Well, I think that code is improvable, but its just to give you an idea how to solve that.